# Inserting into database, echo shows correct value, UPDATE multiplies it?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update some entries in my database, basically I am counting the number of checkboxes that have been selected on the previous page and multiplying them with 25 then adding that value to the current value in the DB.

This is my code:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['code_approve'])
  {
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++)
    {
      $approval_id = $checkbox[$i];
      $checkboxCount = count($_POST['checkbox']);
      $countx25 = $checkboxCount * 25;
      $sql = "UPDATE table SET status='approved', used='processed' WHERE id='$approval_id'";
      $sql2 = "UPDATE members SET balance = balance+'$countx25'";
      $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if($result)
    {
      echo "$countx25";
    }
   }
 ?>
```

It seems, that for some reason it is multiplying $countx25 with the number of checkboxes before inserting it into MySQL. This  `if($result){echo "$countx25";}}` always shows me the right value though.

If i select 1 it prints 25, 2 prints 50, 3 prints 75 and so on, but for the MySQL part, if i select 1 it adds 25 to current value, 2 adds 100, 3 adds 225 ?!

What's the error here ?

Comment: Well no, unless  `3 * 25 = 225` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment. You are running this for each checkbox you get via $_POST. Why do you even use the for loop if you use `count` to count the checkboxes. Remove the for loop and it will work as you intend it to.

Answer (score 3):

In your SQL query:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE members SET balance = balance+'$countx25'";
```

You don't tell the database which row to update, so all rows are updated. While you test, you first test once, then again and again, so it might add to fields you don't expect it to. Probably this is your problem.

To specify which row to update, use a [`WHERE` clause<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

To prevent updating the same field more than once, execute the query only once.

Comment: Hey, there is only 1 row in the database so I thought it doesn't really matter, but for the sake of completion i added `WHERE member_id='2'` (which is the only row), this did not solve the problem though :-(

Comment: @user990767: This is because you obviously do the update for each entry you get via the $_POST superglobal. Just remove the for loop ... theres no point to it anyway

Comment: It helps if you - for debug purposes - output the actual SQL query you execute. You can then use PHPMyAdmin (or something similar) to test independent to your script what the SQL query does. This can help to find the problem as well. What you write about the row is correct then, but keep in mind that with each query you will add the value, that's what [TomS wrote as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8593937/367456). **And** indent your code properly, then you see how Dan writes, that you're executing the query in a loop (multiple times). So you add it multiple times.

Comment: @Dan Could you please post that as answer so I can accept it as such, this did work actually.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop in your code is the problem. I guess here you are trying to use all checkboxes in the previous page, for your code you loop for all the checkboxes, so if there are 4 checkboxes, the for loop will run 4 times. So please identify what you want to do.

This is your code.

```
<?php
if($_POST['code_approve'])
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++)
    {
        $approval_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $checkboxCount = count($_POST['checkbox']);
        $countx25 = $checkboxCount * 25;
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET status='approved', used='processed' WHERE id='$approval_id'";
        $sql2 = "UPDATE members SET balance = balance+'$countx25'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if($result)
    {
        echo "$countx25";
    }
}
```

?>